# Interpreting opensmile feature output

Tags: audeering-opensmile

My output features have -0 and -1 appended to them, what does it mean? For example, I have both pcm_RMSenergy_sma_amean-0 and pcm_RMSenergy_sma_amean-1, with different values. This happens using GeMAPSv01a.conf and IS10_paraling.conf config files (haven't checked with others).